# Enabling C++14 in clang in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++14

I've installed clang 3.7 and I'm using it with visual studio. When I try to compile:

```
auto f()
{
return 2;
}
```

I'm getting error saying that this is future from C++14. I've tried to pass:
-std=c++14 as compiler arguments but then I'm getting error:

Error   1   error : unknown argument: '-std=c++14'  *C:\Users...\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8\clang-cl.exe  ConsoleApplication8.*

Any ideas how to enable c++14 features in clang under Visual Studio 2013?

Edit:
I have to add that I am able to compile and build c++11 code with this compiler under Visual Studio without any problems.

Comment: Reading http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html makes me think: you have a brave heart

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`clang-cl` doesn't use the same option syntax as traditional clang - it's supposed to mimic Visual Studio's `cl` command line, not `clang`'s command line.

For instance, from `clang-cl`'s [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl):

```
CL.EXE COMPATIBILITY OPTIONS:
  /?                     Display available options
  /arch:<value>          Set architecture for code generation
  /C                     Don't discard comments when preprocessing
  /c                     Compile only
  /D <macro[=value]>     Define macro
  ...
```

Notice that those options are similar to Microsoft's `cl` option syntax, not `clang`'s option syntax.

However, they have a little pass-through option to support cases like yours:

```
OPTIONS:
  ...
  -Xclang <arg>         Pass <arg> to the clang compiler
  -mllvm <value>        Additional arguments to forward to LLVM's option processing
```

And so it would seem that invoking `clang-cl -Xclang -std=c++14` would be your best bet.

Comment: @andiduh hi, I want to thank you for your answer, it worked!!! Thank you very much. Would you have any idea why can't we just pass the -std=c++14 option? That is, why they didn't that way so we can use that option without 'Xclang'? I mean we do use clang compiler, why not to be able to simply pass arguments to it?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando Complete guess: The shim is designed to accept arguments that VS wants to pass it its compiler (cl).  Rather than teach VS how to talk to clang, they wrote a ship (clang-cl) that translates arguements that VS would use to talk to cl into clang-ese.  If you want to talk *directly* to clang, you have to "escape" your argument.  Passing "any argument clang-cl does not know to be a cl argument" to clang would be a dangerous mess: whitelisting is safer than blacklisting.

Answer (score 6):

I work on clang-cl. As antiduh says, clang-cl tries to mimic Visual Studio's `cl`. `cl` up to and including c++14 didn't have a switch for enabling language modes, it just always enabled all the latest stuff. Hence, clang-cl does too. MSVC gained some C++14 support in MSVC 2015, so if you tell clang-cl that you want it to emulate MSVC 2015 or later, it will automatically enable C++14. clang-cl by default emulates the version of MSVC found on your system. You can explicitly pass `-fmsc-version=1900` to force emulation of 2015, which will then implicitly enable C++14.

As of MSVC 2017, cl.exe supports a [`/std:` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version), so clang-cl supports that too. It can be used to enable C++14 (the lowest level), C++17, C++20, or the newest-known version.

The `-Xclang` flags are internal flags and are not considered a stable interface. So do not use those.

Comment: Thanks for filling in the background. But regarding this statement "The -Xclang flags are internal flags and are not considered a stable interface" - why is '-XClang' part of the help text? It's not internal if its widely advertised.